# How to set Excel sheet name with powershell variable?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set an excel sheet name with Powershell using a variable but am getting this error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:14 char:1
+ $ws.Name = $RequestTitle
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
# create new excel object 
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

# show the excel object 
$excel.visible = $True

# add a workbook 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

# create a variable referencing the first sheet of the wb
$ws= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# change the name of the sheet 
$ws.Name = $NewSheetName
```

But when I do something like: `$ws.Name = "some string"` it works fine without an error. I've also tried using the `$NewSheetName.ToString()` method to no avail.

What is the best way to reference a variable to name a sheet? Any help would appreciated!

Comment: What is in `$NewSheetName`. Worksheet names cannot have more than 31 characters and using the space is not recommended.
The names must be unique within the workbook and cannot contain any of the following characters \  /  *  ?  :  [  ]

Comment: `$NewSheetName` is a string. Even if defining this way:
`$NewSheetName = "some string" ` 
`$ws.Name = $NewSheetName`

results in the same error.

It's the only sheet in the workbook right now.

Comment: Can you try a name without space? `$NewSheetName = "some_string"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the statement like this will take care of it. Put quotes around the variable name.

```
# change the name of the sheet 
$ws.Name = "$NewSheetName"
```

I dont know why but excel sheet name requires a string in quotes even when using a variable that's clearly a string.

**Note**

Tested with powershell v5 and Office 2013, Office 365, Code with $variable without quote works fine. Not sure what exactly is causing the issue where you are required to use `double quotes` around the variable name.

Comment: Intriguing; can we narrow the need for this obscure workaround down a bit? It's not necessary for me on Windows PowerShell v5.1.18362.628 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit; Version 1909, OS Build: 18363.657), for instance (PS Core versions on the same OS work fine too).

Comment: I am on powershell 5.1.16299.1146 with Windows 10 Enterprise and its not a problem. @WillRoddy would you be able to provide the OS version and powershell version along with the Office version you are using ?

Comment: Yes - powershell 5.1.18362.628 (same as @mklement0). Win10 Pro (64-Bit, version 1903, OS build 18362.657) with Office 365 version 2001 (build 12430.20184). Maybe it's a 365 problem?

Comment: @mklement0 tested with Office 365 and it works there as well.